# React-table: save accessor value in state with checkbox

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to use the react-table as a checkbox table. The first column will be the checkboxes, when a checkbox gets selected i want to save the id that was defined in the accessor in the state.

I have been looking at the examples and made my way trough the official documentation, so far without much luck.

My code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import 'react-table/react-table.css'

export default class TableAccessor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { personId: null }

     //Data to show inside the table, when an item gets selected the ID has to be set in the state
    this.data= [
      {id: 1, first_name: 'Emma', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'emma@example.com'},
      {id: 2, first_name: 'Liam', last_name: 'Miller', email: 'liam@example.com'}
    ];

    //Header data for the table
    this.columns = [
      {Header: '#', accessor: 'id', Cell: () => <input onChange={() => {
        //Here i want to get the ID of the selected item defined in this.data
        this.setState({personId: this.data.id});
      }} type="checkbox"></input>},
      {Header: 'First name', accessor: 'first_name'},
      {Header: 'Last name', accessor: 'last_name'},
      {Header: 'Email', accessor: 'email'}
    ];

  }

  logger = () => {
    console.log("personId: " + this.state.personId)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="wrapper">
        <button onClick={this.logger}>Print</button>
        <ReactTable data={this.data} columns={this.columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I also want to be able to only check one checkbox at the time. I saw people solving this with radio buttons, however when i change the `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"` i can still select more than one item.

Who can help me overcome this issue and explain me what the best way is to save the accessor value in the state?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why would you use `react-table` package? What is the benefit of using 3rd party package instead of writing it yourself?

Steps I'd take:

1. Write static HTML table with stuff you need
2. Map the `data` array to the table rows and populate it. Make sure to add `data-id` attribute and pass the `id attribute` from the array to each element
3. Add `onClick` handlers which get the `data-id` attribute when clicked.
4. You can use computed property names (example [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/videos/computed-property-names/)) and generate state like this: `this.setState( {[savedId]: value} )`

And that should be it.